# Trouble binding to an NSCollectionView and an NSArrayController programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding

I have duplicated an Apple code [example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CollectionViews/Introduction/Introduction.html) (Quick Start for Collection Views) demonstrating how to bind a NSCollectionView to an NSArrayController using nib instantiated objects in Xcode.  It works fine.

I am trying to make a very similar binding between these same classes in my own application.
I need to create my bindings programmatically and am not having success translating the bindings I created in Xcode to objective-c code.  For a variety of reasons I need to instantiate the NSArrayController and the NSCollectionView in separate classes.  I have chosen to use a simple nib file for the collection prototype view.

In a "FileManager" class, I have an NSMutableArray *_messageArray and an NSArrayController *_messageController which I bind:

```
[_messageController setContent:_messageArray];
[_messageController bind:@"contentArray" toObject:self 
                           withKeyPath:@"messageArray" options:nil];
```

I place several instances of the simple object, MessageListing, into messageArray for testing:

```
@interface MessageListing : NSObject {
    NSString *_messageName;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *messageName;
```

In a "ViewManager" class, I create an NSCollectionView *messageCollectionView, load the prototype view, _messageListingPrototype, from a nib -- which includes an NSTextField *messageNamePrototype, create an NSCollectionViewItem *messageListingItem, and set its represented object to be an instance of MessageListing.

```
NSCollectionViewItem *messageListingItem = [[NSCollectionViewItem alloc] init];
[messageListingItem setView:_messageListingPrototype];
MessageListing *messageListing = [[MessageListing alloc] init];
[messageListingItem setRepresentedObject:messageListing];
[messageCollectionView setItemPrototype:messageListingItem];

// create bindings between the subviews and the collection view

[_messageNamePrototype bind:@"value" toObject:messageListingItem 
                    withKeyPath:@"representedObject.messageName" options:nil];
```

And in my AppDelegate I bind the ViewManager's NSCollectionView with the File Manager's NSArrayController:

```
[viewManager.messageCollectionView bind:@"content"
             toObject:fileManager.messageController
                   withKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects" options:nil];
```

I do not receive any KVC exceptions. Explicit requests for the NSCollectionView to display after the bindings have been initialized and the array filled with instances still do not cause the NSCollectionView to display any messageListingPrototype views.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Still a mystery.  I did some re-archetecting and made most of my bindings in a XIB instead.  Not sure why the above doesn't work.